# Salesforce Classic Email Template in Quick Find Not Found

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities

In Salesforce Lightning view, I'm having issue finding the "Classic Email Templates" in Setup >> Quick Find.

I tried looking at the Profiles >> System Administrator profile >> System Permissions. I assured that the Manage Public Classic Email Templates & Edit HTML Templates are selected.

Do you know how to solve this?

[Classic Email Template not found under the Email Section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ApbZ.png)

Comment: I see in your comments that you you've submitted a support case for this, that is good. I'm also seeing this in several orgs, and have heard of others seeing it too. I submitted a support case earlier this week, don't have an answer yet, but I'll post back here if/when I do.

Answer (score 10):

So finally this issue was fixed. SF responded to the case created. You need to go company information and click Match Production Licenses. You will receive and email shortly and after that you should be able to see the classic email templates in the quick find box.

Comment: This works. Can this be set as the correct answer?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be somehting going around. Last week I noticed Classic email templates missing in my org too. Luckily it's just my trial or and so far it hasn't hit our clients yet.

I too have a case in and they can't figure it out either.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. could it be that the org never had any classic emails, just lightning ones? What do you get when you force navigate to `/lightning/setup/CommunicationTemplatesEmail/home` or switch to Classic UI?

What's your org's edition, compare with https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.admin_viewing_emailtemplates.htm&type=5, maybe check your user's profile for the right checkboxes?

Comment: A week ago I was able to find the "Classic Email Templates" in the Quick Find. Right now, I have to switch to classic view, and I can find the Classic Email Templates.

XXX/lightning/setup/CommunicationTemplatesEmail/home >> I got "Page not found"

I believe it's Salesforce Summer 2022 edition.

Comment: I also confirmed that >> Edit HTML Templates, Customize Application,Manage Public Classic Email Templates are given to the profile permissions

Comment: Everybody's on summer release, I'm asking about Edition as in Group, Performance, Unlimited. Should be in every page's title when you hover over browser's tab or check Setup -> Company Information. Weird, you might have to make a ticket with sf support

Comment: It is an Unlimited edition. 
Thank you, I will submit a SF support ticket.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. I raised the ticket with SF, however not sure if there would be a response. In the meantime, I was able to locate the email templates by running a query through salesforce inspector. You can query on the emailTemplate table and it will show all the templates that you can open in SF and edit.

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue. meanwhile as a work around I am opening the existing email templates from email alerts.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here's the Known Issues:

https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000002ykW1QAI

If you're on a dev org, you'll have to ask your AE to enable it at the moment.

I was told it would be fixed, but I don't know.